# How to avoid auto login in multiple domain when authenticating with OpenId

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, openid

We would like to apply AzureAD to authenticate the website. Currently, the project has 2 different domains one for develop, one for production.

**For example:**

- production.azurewebsites.net
- develop.azurewebsites.net

The issue is, whenever we login on the develop domain (develop.azurewebsites.net), it also auto login into production environment (production.azurewebsites.net) as the same user that we logged in on develop one.

**Question:** 
- How can we tell the system to ask users to choose login account **once** for each domain that they try to login? since we don't want we login to production environment incidentally

Thanks for helps!

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});

services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(AzureADDefaults.CookieScheme, options =>
{
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
});

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Login/SignIn";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Login/SignIn";
}); 

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";

    options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = (context) =>
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("/Login/SignIn");
        context.HandleResponse();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see why this should be an issue. At the end of the day this is very typical example of what SSO is. Changing this behavior might have negative impact on enduser experience (ypu help developers, but you harm end user, because they will be prompted).

The way to change this is to change the [Prompt property of OpenIdConnectOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectoptions.prompt?view=aspnetcore-2.2) object right after you set the Authority. The least harmful value would be `select_account`. This will introduce an interuption of the SSO process, so the user will have to chose an account to sign in.

Comment: What we have done in an app is to offer an option for the user. If they click Login, no prompt is passed. If they click Select O365 Account, prompt=select_account is passed. I agree, in most cases you want SSO to work and you don't want to disable it. It's mostly an issue for consultants like me who have many accounts.

Comment: Actually, what we want is asking users to login once for each domain. Like separate the SSO process between environments or domains rather than asking for logins every time users access the website